# Add space at nth possition on a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
# 2022  5  2  8  1 24.8-17.1800 -66.3260   3.6  0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0    2
SOD6   2.20 1.00 P
SOD6   3.98 1.00 S
SOD5   3.21 1.00 P
SOD5   5.79 1.00 S
SOD0   4.07 1.00 P
SOD0   7.10 1.00 S
SOD3   6.47 1.00 P
SOD3  11.20 1.00 S
# 2022  5  3  0 10 16.8-17.3820 -65.6330  28.0  0.7 0.0 0.0 0.3    3
SOD2   6.24 1.00 P
SOD2  10.49 1.00 S
SOD9   7.66 1.00 P
SOD9  12.75 1.00 S
SOD1  10.34 1.00 P
SOD3  11.42 1.00 P
SOD3  21.11 1.00 S
# 2022  5  3 11 28 10.8-17.7600 -65.9840   6.6  0.7 0.0 0.0 0.1    4
SOD3   6.55 1.00 P
SOD2   6.89 1.00 P
SOD2  11.70 1.00 S
SOD9   8.82 1.00 P
SOD1  10.04 1.00 P
SOD1  17.60 1.00 S
```

I was trying to add a black space on the 24th place of each header, this is the header

```
# 2022  5  2  8  1 24.8-17.1800 -66.3260   3.6  0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0    2
```

so the header will look like:

```
# 2022  5  2  8  1 24.8 -17.1800 -66.3260   3.6  0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0    2
```

I tried the following code:

```
# To read the headers and to add a space on 24th place 
# of each header, where 'phase.dat' is the csv file
grep '# 2022' phase.dat | sed 's/ ./&\s /24'
```

But it did not add  the space at desired position.
Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

Stay safe and best regards,
Tonino

Comment: If its always the first `-` `sed -e 's/-/ -/'` should work.

Comment: What's your field separator in your CSV?

Comment: @Cyrus, only spaces, not a tabulationn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
sed 's/^\(# 2022[^-]*\)\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' phase.dat
```

If the headers are what you're actually trying to extract and edit.

```
sed -n 's/^\(# 2022[^-]*\)\(.*\)$/\1 \2/p' phase.dat
```

---

A quick breakdown on the `sed` code

- `^` is what they call an anchor in regex, It means from the beginning or start.
- `( )` Inside of those parenthesis are capture groups. Since it is B.R.E. (Basic Regular Expression) It needs to be escaped/preceded by a `\`
- `[ ]` Is what they call a bracket expression,

  - inside it is also a `^` (it negates) but that means everything EXCEPT for the character next to it, in this case a `-`
  - `*` is a next to `[ ]`, they call it a quantifier, which means zero or more string/characters.
- So the first capture group will match `# 2022` from the beginning and everything until it reaches the first `-`
- `(.*)` is the second capture group.

  - `.*` means zero or more amount of string/character, which basically the rest of the string is captured.
- `$` is also an anchor which means at the end.
- `\1` and `\2` refers to the capture groups one and two, which is what ever is inside the `( )`

---

- See [`man 7 regex`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)

Comment: works, what does "(.*\)$/\1 \2/" mean?, thanks in advance

Comment: @tonino, I've updated the answer with some short info.

Answer (score 1):

Replace \s with a space as shown below

```
grep '# 2022' phase.dat | sed 's/./& /24'
# 2022  5  2  8  1 24.8- 17.1800 -66.3260   3.6  0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0    2
# 2022  5  3  0 10 16.8- 17.3820 -65.6330  28.0  0.7 0.0 0.0 0.3    3
# 2022  5  3 11 28 10.8- 17.7600 -65.9840   6.6  0.7 0.0 0.0 0.1    4
```